# Can I crop and overlay at same time when useing ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, filter

I have two command:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf crop='1280:720:0:0' -acodec copy croped.mp4
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 1.jpg -i  croped.mp4 -filter_complex 'overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:shortest=1,format=yuv420p' -c:a copy result.mp4
```

Can these be combined into a single command? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant guys. Anyway, [filtergraph](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) uses label to handle one filter after another. In your case, you may try

```
ffmpeg -y -i vide.ts -i logo.png  -filter_complex "[0:v]crop=1280:720:0:0[crop]; [crop]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[out]" -map [out] -map 0:a crop_overlay.mp4
```